# ¿Como formatear una consulta SQL para recibir parámetros en marcadores de posicion(?) en vez de (%s) en Python2.7?

Tags: python, sql, python-2.x

Estoy tratando de realizar una inserción SQL, usando `mysql.connector for python2.7` en Python2.7, usando el uso de parámetros pasados con marcadores de posición`(?)` pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
"Not all parameters where used in the SQL statement".
```

El fin es: **Evitar inyección SQL**, teniendo una subpregunta:

> ¿usar `(?)` es mas seguro que `(%s)`?

---

Este es el código:

```
import mysql.connector
con=mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password="",host="127.0.0.1",database="bdpython")
cursor=con.cursor()
#DATOS
id=1
nombre="juan"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (id,datos) VALUES(?,?)",(id,nombre,))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

---

Estuve leyendo y encontré varias formas de asignar los valores:

1) No se aceptan tuplas: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (id,datos) VALUES(?,?)",((id,)(nombre,))`

2) "Not all parameters where used id the SQL statement":

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (id) VALUES(?)",(id,))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (datos) VALUES(?)",(nombre,))
```

3) Usando `%s` en vez de `(?)` funciona: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (id,datos) VALUES(%s,%s)",(ids,nombre))`

---

Leyendo observe que habia un error de formateo, es posible hacerlo de la siguiente manera, usando `mysql.connector`

```
var="1"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ejemplo WHERE id='?'",var)
```

Comment: En parte el principal problema era por error de formateo, pero la pregunta posee una buena respuesta ya que, la forma correcta seria usar `%s` evitando problemas al no poseer un conector predeterminado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así es, lo correcto es usar `%s` y no `?`. La documentación sobre el módulo no parece reconocer `?` para el formateo (sin embargo, me parece que otros conectores si lo reconocen). Esto lo puedes ver en los ejemplos de [Inserting Data Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

Por lo tanto, tu código debería verse como:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ejemplo (id,datos) VALUES(%s,%s)",(id,nombre,))
```

Con respecto a la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), la documentación comenta un poco sobre este tema ([Guidelines for Python Developers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-coding.html)):

> The bad data might also be deliberate, representing an “SQL injection”
>   attack. For example, input values might contain quotation marks,
>   semicolons, % and _ wildcard characters and other characters
>   significant in SQL statements. Validate input values to make sure they
>   have only the expected characters. Escape any special characters that
>   could change the intended behavior when substituted into an SQL
>   statement. Never concatenate a user input value into an SQL statement
>   without doing validation and escaping first. Even when accepting input
>   generated by some other program, expect that the other program could
>   also have been compromised and be sending you incorrect or malicious
>   data.

Que, en resumidas cuentas, debes considerar:

1. Valida los datos inputados
2. Valida los caracteres especiales (conocido como "escaping").
3. Nunca concatenes información inputada por los usuarios.
4. Valida información si vienen de programas externos.

---

### Bonus

Sobre tu duda con las comas dentro de las tuplas. Observa esto:

```
>>> (10)
10
```

¿Cómo diferencias las tuplas que contienen un elemento?. ¿Es `(10)` una tupla? La respuesta es **NO**. Para Python `(10)` es solo evaluar lo que se encuentra dentro del paréntesis, es decir, un entero.

Entonces, ¿cómo diferencia Python esto?, ¿cómo creo una tupla de un solo elemento? Aquí es donde la coma entra en el juego, para decirle a Python que quieres una tupla de un elemento tienes que agregar una coma al final:

```
>>> (10,)
(10,)
```

Es por esta razón por la cual tanto en las listas y tuplas puedes tener una coma al final sin problemas, para Python esto es sintácticamente correcto:

```
>>> [10,20,]
[10, 20]
>>> (30,40,50,)
(30, 40, 50)
```

Comment: El corrector ortográfico cambio la palabra

Comment: ¿por que se usa esto asi: `(id,dato,)` sobrando una coma?

Comment: @Victor-Random observa mi actualización

Comment: Excelente actualización, nunca había pensado en una tupla de un elemento :)